# Classify a conic on a plane

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Given a conic 
*C* : $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^2+y^2+z^2-6y = 0 \\ 
x-y+z=0 \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
 How can i classify *C* defined as an orthogonal projection of *C* on the plane z=0 and how to find the equation ( in canonical form ) of it in this case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can eliminate the variable $z$

Answer (score 1):

Classification is easy: The intersection of a sphere with a plane is a circle or a single point. The circle’s orthogonal projection onto $z=0$ is an ellipse (unless the cutting plane is perpendicular to $z=0$, which it’s not).

As for finding an equation for this ellipse, various methods are available, but in this case simply eliminating $z$ from the system, as suggested by Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, is the simplest. You might also want to take a look at [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3293841/how-can-i-classify-a-conic-given-by-x2xy3y2-4x-0-and-xyz-2-0?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

The conic $C$, which is the orthogonal projection onto the plane $z=0$, can be obtained from replacing $z$ in the equation

$$
\begin{array}{c}
x^2+y^2+z^2-6y = 0 \\ 
\end{array}
$$

with $z= y-x$, which results in

$$x^2+y^2-(x+3)y = 0$$

In order to cast the above conic into its canonical form, the following substitutions can be used,

$$x+3=u+v, \>\>\>\>\> y=u-v$$

which leads to its canonical equation

$$\frac{(u-3)^2}{3}+\frac{(v-1)^2}{1}=1$$

As can be seen explicitly, the conic $C$ is an eclipse.